# Facebook Graph API Swift Fetch

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a problem using Facebook Graph API. The connection is made by `Firebase` in `login.swift`.

**My Facebook login button code:**

```
public func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!)
{
    loginAlert.isHidden = false

    if error != nil {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    } else if (result.isCancelled){ // Canceled by user
        print("user canceled sign up")
        loginAlert.text = "Canceled"
    } else {

        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in // Sign in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.ref.child("Users").child(user!.uid).child("Name").setValue(user?.displayName)
        })

        print("user logged with facebook -> WalkThrough")

        loginAlert.text = "Successfuly logged in!"


        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 2) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: { () -> Void in

            transitionSegue.segue.switchToWalkThrough() // Segue
        })
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to fetch data from Graph API in `profile.swift`.

**My fetch data function:**

```
func getUserFacebookDataAndFriends() {
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        let parameters = ["fields": "email, id, name"]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters)

        _ = graphRequest?.start { connection, result, error in
            // If something went wrong, we're logged out
            if (error != nil) {
                // Clear email, but ignore error for now
                return
            }



        } // End of graph request
    }
}
```

But it returns directly. The only way to fetch data from Facebook is during the user login process.
I think that the app loses the facebook token when the user is already logged in, then Firebase is taking over while saving the Facebook user.

Someone has the solution for it ?